# Multiple image upload only append the last data in Axios post but not each of the data

Tags: vue.js, axios

i am trying to upload multiple images. However i created a for loop in my methods after clicking the post button. But when im posting in axios. it post twice in the api but the image that is saving is only the last index of the this.file data. Can anyone help me? Thank you

This is the code i created

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-brattain-w3hsb?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: You cannot be using both [tag:vuejs2] and [tag:vuejs3] so which is it? Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Links to remote code repositories are not suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the problem but as I can see you use the same formData object for every call. I think you should initialize FormData in the loop, it can cause strange cases.

By the way, I think you can submit multiple files in one axios call too:

```
postitem() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < this.file.length; i++) {
        var obj = this.file[i];
        formData.append("filename[]", obj);
      }
      axios.post(`url/test/postimages`, formData, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token()}`,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        }).then((response) => {
          if (response.status === "error") {
            alert("error");
            this.loading = false;
          } else {
            alert("success");
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: sorry is it like i need to put the form data inside the loop?

Comment: Yep in this case, because you would like to post every file separately.

Comment: Hi, sorry  when i try to use teh one u edit. its giving me an error because of this formData.append("filename[]", obj);  the error says  "message": "Call to a member function store() on array"

Comment: i also try to put the formdata inside the for loop. that one is working but the issue is the alert(success) is also showing 2 times depends on how many images i upload i think its because i put in the for loop

Comment: I edited my answer, added `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`header

Comment: I already added this 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' header but still showing me this error  the error says "message": "Call to a member function store() on array"

Comment: Can i ask what is this  formData.append("filename[]", obj); ? cause in the api the field name required is filename. can i ask why we put filename[]?

Comment: with the [] it will be an array on the server side and you can access all the files you appended on client side

Comment: ohhh thank you. but when i put that , i also already add the  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'  but its showing me error "Call to a member function store() on array" . i dont know why

Comment: Can you paste the whole exception here?

Comment: {
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "/var/www/name/app/Http/Controllers/API/Item_ImageController.php",
    "line": 31,
   
} sorry is it this one?

Comment: ah, so it's an error on your backend / server side right? 
You can change the server side code too because now the filenames is an array

Comment: ohh so its because of the backend thats why its showing error?

Comment: yes I think, because the append works for me. Can You sign this as a correct answer because the server side is out of context for this thread. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much sorry for taking your timeee really thank youu

Comment: No worries, that's why this site exists, to help each other :) Thanks for the points.